# Get sum of specific entries in php array

Tags: php, json

I have written a php script that outputs the following from an api:

```
    array(197) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["buyer_email"]=>
    string(25) "*****@live.co.uk"
    ["total"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "0.10"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "6.41"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["buyer_email"]=>
    string(19) "*****@hotmail.com"
    ["total"]=>
    array(8) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "7.00"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "7.50"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "10.14"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "17.69"
      [4]=>
      string(5) "10.14"
      [5]=>
      string(5) "10.14"
      [6]=>
      string(5) "10.14"
      [7]=>
      string(5) "10.14"
    }
  }
```

This basically shows the purchases done by each user. I would like to have the sum of all the user's purchases. For example
`"buyer_email": ****@live.co.uk, "total" : 6.51`

I have tried this solution suggested by Luca:

```
$json = '{"buyer_email":"****@live.co.uk","total":["0.10","6.41"]}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
$total = $obj->{'total'};

$sumTotal = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($total); $i++){
$sumTotal += $total[$i];
}

print $sumTotal;
```

It works for an individual entry but not when there is more than one?

Comment: you need to parse then with json_decode, create a logic to sum and encode again.

Answer (score 1):

That work:

```
$json = '{"buyer_email":"****@live.co.uk","total":["0.10","6.41"]}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
$total = $obj->{'total'};

$sumTotal = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($total); $i++){
$sumTotal += $total[$i];
}

print $sumTotal;
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. Maybe because I have more than one array of this type? As in more the one buyer.